# image scaling performance in Quartz/Cocoa vs Qt4

Tags: cocoa, qt4, quartz-graphics, scale

I wrote a test application in Qt4 which uses QImage.scaled() or QPixmap.scaled() methods that turned to  be very slow. Even a perspective transform is faster, while a scaling transform is the same slow.
[I tried to scale directly a QPainter but I do not master paintEvent() so I always get "painter not active" or paintEvent() is not called at all. So I do not know the painter scaling performaces.]
I ask here if the same issue is known for Quartz/Cocoa or instead their performances for similar tasks are better. I am particularly interested in native Quartz pdf rendering capability and subsequent image scaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NIRTimer *timer = [NIRTimer timer];
    [timer start];
    NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:@"filename"];
    NSImage *scaledImage = [[NSImage alloc]initWithSize:NSMakeSize(720, 480)];
    [scaledImage lockFocus];
    [image drawInRect:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 720, 480) fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeSourceAtop fraction:1];
    [scaledImage unlockFocus];
    [image release];
    [scaledImage release];
    NSLog(@"time: %ld", [timer microseconds]);
```

This is how to scale an image in Cocoa, and it takes 80000 microseconds (0.08 seconds).

Comment: 80,000 µs is meaningless unless you tell us what system, and compare it against the Qt4 on the same system.  (80 ms is actually quite slow for scaling an image.)

Comment: It would be better to start the measurement after the original image has been created, as this is subject to disk I/O performance.